# PyInstaller permission denied, then command not found Mac Mojave

Tags: python, macos, pycharm, pyinstaller, oh-my-zsh

Trying to use PyInstaller to create a Mac distribution for an application.
Navigating to the directory with my files in it, I type `pyinstaller START_HERE.py`

Output is `zsh: permission denied: pyinstaller`

Then I tried it with `sudo`: `sudo pyinstaller START_HERE.py`

Output is: `sudo: pyinstaller: command not found`

`pip3 show pyinstaller` shows the location as `Location: /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages`

I updated the path on my Mac with `sudo nano /etc/paths`, pasted the above path in, saved, and confirmed that it's in the path with `echo $PATH`.

I don't know how much of the following is relevant, so I am including it all:
Python development in PyCharm (dev was done in Windows, also in PyCharm),
Mac is using iTerm with Oh-My-zsh

I am not sure what else to try and whether the permission thing is a red herring and that somehow I just have the wrong path.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you have a look at https://pyinstaller.readthedocs.io/en/stable/installation.html#installing-in-mac-os-x
It sounds that pyinstaller should be found in more standard locations.

Comment: That's helpful- python was installed via homebrew and is in the directory listed in the docs.  But PyInstaller was not.  Will look into that.

Comment: I re-installed pyinstaller with homebrew rather than pip, copied the locations from the brew install notes to the path, and it works now.

Answer (score 0):

For pyinstaller to create an .exe file the command line should be:

```
pyinstaller --onefile FileName.py
```

Comment: Same result.  Also, I want 1 directory rather than a single executable.